# SPARQL Query error in python (First example)

Tags: python-2.7, sparql

```
import rdflib
g = rdflib.Graph()

g.load("chck.rdf")

for row in g.query(
        'select ?s where { [] foaf:knows ?s .}'):
    print(row.s)
```

Note:- `chck.rdf` was in the same directory

**The error is:-**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python27/exmpl/four.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       g.load("chck.rdf")
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1046, in
>   load
>       self.parse(source, publicID, format)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1039, in
>   parse
>       parser.parse(source, self, **args)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\rdfxml.py", line
>   577, in parse
>       self._parser.parse(source)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
>       xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
>       self.feed(buffer)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
>       self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
>       raise exception
>
> SAXParseException: file:///C:/Python27/exmpl/chck.rdf:132:19: not
>   well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: It looks like loading of the data failed. Is it proper RDF?

Comment: I resolved the problem, foaf was undefined which led to errors

Comment: Ok, then please provide it as answer and mark it as resolved by "accept" your own answer.